# Remove items from an array, reorder the items, then put it back (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Here's my code:

```js
reorder = (dragItemId, startIndex, endIndex) => {
        //find the element in the this.state.feladatok which has the same id i pass with reorder
    const dragElem = this.state.feladatok.find(elem => dragItemId === elem.id);
        //find all elements which has the same szid which dragElem has,
        //then sort them. The lista is an array, a piece of this.state.feladatok
    const lista = this.state.feladatok.filter(listaelem => listaelem.szid === dragElem.szid).sort((a, b) => a.rang - b.rang);
      //i need here to remove lista from this.state.feladatok
    const [removed] = lista.splice(startIndex, 1);
    lista.splice(endIndex, 0, removed)
      //now i need to put it back
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/rangvalt', {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            lista: lista
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(ujlista => this.setState({feladatok: ujlista}))
      //because waiting for this response is too slow
    .catch(err => console.log(err)) ;
    }
```

Here's a function that i use in react, and works well, but waiting for the response of the server cause UX problems, what i can (i think) easily solve with updating not just server side, but immediately in client side. The main problem here is removing. So how to expand the methods of `lista` to not just get, and sort, but remove them with `setState()`(or something else)?

Comment: Can you clarify your question... are you just asking how to remove an item from an array within your component state?

Comment: The react and server things doesn't matter. If i assign the state to a variable, then delete the `lista` from that, reorder, then set the state as concatenating the `lista`, and the array where the `lista` deleted from, then it's all done. I just want to know the proper JS method to that.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would add the element to `endIndex`. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you shouldn't need `startIndex`.

```
const dragElem = this.state.feladatok.find(elem => dragItemId === elem.id);
// Remove dragElem from array
const lista = this.state.feladatok.filter(listaelem => listaelem.szid === dragElem.szid).sort((a, b) => a.rang - b.rang);

// Insert dragElem into lista at index endIndex
const newLista = [...lista.slice(0, endIndex), dragElem, ...lista.slice(endIndex)];
this.setState({feladatok: newLista});
```

Comment: I have already been moved the element from startindex to endindex. It's a bit hard to explain what's happening. I'm working with the objects of the this.state.feladatok array. First, i find an element, then find the elements in the this.state.feladatok, which has similar properties. This is the array, named `lista`. Inside the `lista` i reorder the items. It's working. But i want the whole `lista` to delete from the this.state.feladatok array, then put the `lista` back to the this.state.feladatok array.